# Javascript inline scripts and defer scripts order of execution

Tags: javascript

I have a question about order of execution for mixed script type.

Here is my code :

```
    <script>
        if(document.documentMode) {

            const firstScriptInDOM = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            const polyfill = document.createElement('script');
            polyfill.src = "/static/js/polyfills/polyfills.js";
            firstScriptInDOM.parentNode.insertBefore(polyfill, firstScriptInDOM);
        }
    </script>

    <script src="static/js/lib1.js" defer></script>
    <script src="static/js/lib2.js" defer></script>
    <script src="static/js/lib3.js" defer></script>
    <script src="static/js/myOwnScriptFile.js" defer></script>
```

The first script tag's purpose is to load polyfills for IE if the browser is IE.
Then it should load this other scripts and execute my code.

My question is : **Will the polyfills script block execution of the defered scripts ?**

Thanks a lot for you time !

Comment: Question : your first script :

<script>
        if(document.documentMode) {

            const firstScriptInDOM = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            const polyfill = document.createElement('script');
            polyfill.src = "/static/js/polyfills/polyfills.js";
            firstScriptInDOM.parentNode.insertBefore(polyfill, firstScriptInDOM);
        }
    </script>


Is the source code of myOwnScriptFile.js script ?

Comment: No, it is not. My first script loads only polyfills for IE if needed.
myOwnScriptFile.js is my main script with the code for all browsers (including IE which has been polyfilled if needed).

Comment: Interesting... Might that be random? Scripts inserted through DOM manips are loaded asynchronously. So if it takes less time to load it than to parse the DOM could they fire before? ... Anyway, don't rely on this, there are more chances that they won't have been executed. Solutions are: load the polyfill for everyone, or load all the scripts from DOM manips (you'll be able to wait for polyfills.onload if needed)

Comment: Interesting Kaiido. I will do some tests. I didn't want to load an extra file for browser which doesn't need it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scripts load synchronously unless specified to load asynchronously using the `async` attribute, what the `defer` attribute does is that it loads the script only after DOM is loaded. If you append a script dynamically, it will load asynchronously.

In you scenario,

This should be the chain of execution:

- check polyfill script executes
- lib1
- lib2
- lib3
- myOwnScriptFile
- polyfills (downloaded only after the parser has finished execution)

To ensure all your scripts load, in the order you want them too, you could dynamically load all scripts with something like :

check if the browser is IE:

```
IF IE 
 load polyfills, and load other scripts in the onload event of the polyfills script.
ELSE 
 load all other scripts
```

Comment: Oh, that's not good then for what I want to do. So is there a solution to avoid modern browsers to load polyfills.js ?

Comment: @Mourtazag added a basic a idea to the answer itself. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll dig into it. : )

Answer (score 1):

The script which is not deferred will run when it is parsed.
The other scripts will be executed after the document has been parsed in the order in which they appear in the document, before DOMContentLoaded is fired.

### Update

Kaiido is correct and I was a wrong in my conclusion.
The part of your script that adds the polyfill will run first but the script it loads will run asynchronously, as soon as it downloads.
You can see more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Examples).

You can try using [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you think about @Kaiido 's comment above ?

Comment: Thanks ! I'll look at document.write to see if I can get it work.